# Zenity bash command not working with Java

Tags: java, bash, zenity

I'm trying to take input from the user using the zenity command. Here's the command I'm passing to zenity :

```
zenity --question --title "Share File" --text "Do you want to share file?"
```

Here's the code using Java to execute the command :

```
private String[] execute_command_shell(String command)
{
    System.out.println("Command: "+command);
    StringBuffer op = new StringBuffer();
    String out[] = new String[2];
    Process process;
    try
    {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        process.waitFor();
        int exitStatus = process.exitValue();
        out[0] = ""+exitStatus;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            op.append(line + "\n");
        }
        out[1] = op.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return out;
}
```

Although I'm getting an output dialog box, the title has only the first word "Share" and the text of the question also displays only one word "Do"

Is there any explanation to this weird behavior? What's the work around ?

Comment: You have the quotes in the command string variable correctly?

Comment: @EtanReisner the zenity command mentioned on top is the output of the first line of the execute_command_shell method

Comment: You stripped `Command:` off of it then? Ok. Sounds like something isn't parsing the command as a shell command normally then. The answer from WillShackleford covers (though awkwardly) using an array of arguments instead. Which is probably the best answer.

Comment: yes that worked for me. But this makes me wonder how's the Runtime class  implemented and what went wrong with a direct string command.

Comment: Presumably, as WillShackleford also posits, `Runtime` isn't using the shell and is parsing the string itself (and not using shell quoting rules). Presumably this is documented in the class documentation somewhere as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"zenity","--question","--title","Share File","--text","Do you want to share file?"})
```

I would recommend splitting the arguments in the java code so that you can check rather than passing the whole command with quotes.

Here is an example including the splitting to handle quotes:

```
String str = "zenity --question --title \"Share File\" --text \"Do you want to share file?\"";
String quote_unquote[] = str.split("\"");
System.out.println("quote_unquote = " + Arrays.toString(quote_unquote));
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i =0; i < quote_unquote.length; i++) {
    if(i%2 ==0) {
        l.addAll(Arrays.asList(quote_unquote[i].split("[ ]+")));
    }else {
        l.add(quote_unquote[i]);
    }
}
String cmdarray[] = l.toArray(new String[l.size()]);
System.out.println("cmdarray = " + Arrays.toString(cmdarray));
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray);
```

Comment: splitting the command into array of arguments worked for me :) But can you please explain why is it happening so ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the details myself. But as I understand it  when you run a shell, the shell splits the arguments handles quoted blocks etc and zeniity program gets the arguments already split. Here we are bypassing the shell and passing the command more directly on to the operating system which doesn't treat the quotation marks the same way the shell would.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use [UiBooster](https://github.com/Milchreis/UiBooster/) for Java to create this dialog. In that way you don't have to install zenity and you are not limited to linux or gtk on windows.

```java
String userInput = new UiBooster().showTextInputDialog("Do you want to share file?");
```